# Lines with geom_segment does not reach the axis limit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot several lines using `ggplot2` and functions `geom_hline` and `geom_segment`. The problem is that with `geom_segment` it is not possible to reach axis limit. This is not the problem with `geom_hline` but then the plot seems a little bit inconsistent. I also tried to change axis limits but without any success.

Example:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, xend = 4, y = 2.75, yend = 2.75)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 3, xend = 5, y = 3.75, yend = 3.75)) + 
  # xlim(c(2, 5)) # no change
  # xlim(c(2.5, 4.5)) # warning + no geom_segment lines plotted
```

Comment: `ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, xend = 4, y = 2.75, yend = 2.75)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` and use the `limits` parameter of the scale or `coord_cartesian` if you need to specify axis limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `expand` argument to zero to turn off padding

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, xend = 4, y = 2.75, yend = 2.75)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 3, xend = 5, y = 3.75, yend = 3.75)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```